# How can dataframereader read http?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

**My developing environment:**

- Intellij
- Maven
- Scala2.10.6
- win7 x64

**Dependencies:**

```xml
 <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**problem :**
I want read remote csv file into dataframe.
I tried next:

```
val weburl = "http://myurl.com/file.csv"
val tfile = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv(weburl)
```

It returns next Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: http
```

I tried next following internet searching(include stackoverflow)

```
val content = scala.io.Source.fromURL(weburl).mkString
val list = content.split("\n")
//...doing something to string and typecase, seperate each lows to make dataframe format.
```

it works fine, but I think more smart way to loading web source csv file.
Is there any way to DataframeReader can read HTTP csv?

I think setting SparkContext.hadoopConfiguration is some key, so I tried many codes  in internet. but it didn't work and I don't know how to set and each meaning of code lines.

Next is one of my trying and it didn't work.(same error message on accessing "http")

```
val sc = new SparkContext(spark_conf)
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()
val hconf = sc.hadoopConfiguration


hconf.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem].getName)
hconf.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
hconf.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem].getName)
```

Is setting this is key? or not?
Or DataframeReader can't read directly from remote source? than how can i do it?
I need import some special library for http format?

**The thing I want to know** :

Is there any way to dataframereader can read HTTP source?
Without using their own parsing data. (like [[Best way to convert online csv to dataframe scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175124/best-way-to-convert-online-csv-to-dataframe-scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45175124/best-way-to-convert-online-csv-to-dataframe-scala).)
I need to read CSV format. CSV is formal format. I think more general way to read data like `dataframereader.csv("local file"`).

I know this question level too low. I'm sorry for my low-level of understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to read HTTP data directly. Probably the simplest thing you can do is to download file using `SparkFiles`, but it will duplicate data to each worker:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkFiles

spark.sparkContext.addFile("http://myurl.com/file.csv")
spark.read.csv(SparkFiles.get("file.csv"))
```

Personally I'd just download the file upfront and put in a distributed storage.