# Spark read csv file submitted from --files

Tags: apache-spark

I'm submitting a Spark job to a remote spark cluster on yarn and including a file in the spark-submit `--file` I want to read the submitted file as a dataframe. But I'm confused about how to go about this without having to put the file in HDFS:

```
spark-submit \
--class com.Employee \
--master yarn \
--files /User/employee.csv \
--jars SomeJar.jar

spark: SparkSession = // create the Spark Session
val df = spark.read.csv("/User/employee.csv")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can dataframereader read http?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101164/how-can-dataframereader-read-http)

Comment: @DevEx.. was my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("file:///your local file path ")
```

Add file using `addFile` so that it can be available at your worker nodes. Since you want to read local file in cluster mode.

You may need to do a slight change according to scala and the spark version your are using.

Answer (score -1):

`employee.csv` is in the work directory of executor, just reading it as follows:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("employee.csv")
```